# populate 2d array with strings in special order

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to populate my 2d array with a couple of array items. However, I can only figure out how to append one array after the other. What I actually want is to create a new array within my 2d array which contains certain items from the simple array. like this:

> // required result myServerInfos = [  ["www.apple.com", "error", "no
>   data"]    ["www.google.com", "error", "no data"]  ["www.amazon.com",
>   "error", "no data"]   ["www.bla.com", "error", "no data"] ]

These are my arrays:

**swift 4**

```
var myServerInfos = [[String]]()

let pings = ["www.apple.com", "www.google.com", "www.amazon.com", "www.bla.com"]
var statusImagesMain = ["error", "error", "error", "error"]
var serverStatusMain = ["no data", "no data", "no data", "no data"]
```

I know I can access the first array item via "pings.first" and I know I should loop through each of the four arrays, save each of items in a new array and then append them to myServerInfos. I just cannot figure out how to do that concretely.

Comment: You would be better off defining a structure with three properties (or whatever you actually need) and creating an array of that structure. It's far more useful than an unstructured array of array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let myServerInfos = (0..<pings.count).map{ 
  [pings[$0],statusImagesMain[$0],serverStatusMain[$0]] 
}
```

sure all must be of same size

Comment: Note i heavily recommend a struct for an oop approach

Answer (score 0):

[`zip()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) is useful to iterate two arrays (or more generally, sequences)
in parallel. There is at present no corresponding zip function which takes
more than 2 sequences, but with nested `zip()` calls you can get the
required result with

```
let myServerInfos = zip(zip(pings, statusImagesMain), serverStatusMain).map {
    [$0.0, $0.1, $1]
}
```

Comment: yes but note 2 zips and map it may have a performance impact for large content

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for code that reads like your text:

```
var myServerInfos = [[String]]()

let pings = ["www.apple.com", "www.google.com", "www.amazon.com", "www.bla.com"]
var statusImagesMain = ["error", "error", "error", "error"]
var serverStatusMain = ["no data", "no data", "no data", "no data"]

for i in 0 ..< pings.count {
    // one liner version
    let na = [ pings[i], statusImagesMain[i], serverStatusMain[i] ]

    /* shows append use for pushing items.
    var na = [String]()        
    na.append(pings[i])
    na.append(statusImagesMain[i])
    na.append(serverStatusMain[i])
    */

    // push array in
    myServerInfos.append(na)
}
```

Comment: More simply: `let na = [ pings[i], statusImagesMain[i], serverStatusMain[i] ]`